# App in a new sandbox is saying unauthorized access

Tags: appexchange

I have created a new developer sandbox but the app 'cloud extend'  is showing error
unathorized access. how this error can be removed so that the configured app works properly

Comment: Did you consider contacting support of the app provider ?

Comment: when are you getting this error ?
Is it when you are installing or while accessing the APP.

Answer (score 0):

When are you receiving this error ?

If you are getting the error when you are installing the app then please check if your user has the following General User Permissions enabled.
Download AppExchange Packages
Create AppExchange Packages
Upload AppExchange Packages

If you are getting the error when you are accessing the APP, it is usually because of your access to the APP.